# Sequencing a column value based on other column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the SEQ column to be arranged based on PART and BOM combinations. If BOM value is same for a PART value SEQ value should be same, no repeat of sequence, else increment sequence by 1 for different PART-BOM combinations.

Sample data of PART and BOM with expected output for SEQ  as shown below:

```
PART    BOM     SEQ
Part1   BOM1    1
Part1   BOM1    1
Part1   BOM2    2
Part1   BOM2    2
Part1   BOM3    3
Part1   BOM4    4
Part2   BOM12   1
Part2   BOM13   2
Part2   BOM14   3
Part2   BOM15   4
Part2   BOM16   5
Part2   BOM17   6
Part3   BOM14   1
Part4   BOM14   1
Part5   BOM14   1
Part6   BOM14   1
Part7   BOM14   1
```

Comment: Are you planning to store that value in your table, or generate it as part of a query (which is usually better)? Have a look at analytic functions; but what sequence would you want for a part having  say BOM2 and BOM10 - simple alphabetic ordering might not give the result you expect...?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dense_rank` does what you want.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with temp (part, bom) as
  2    (select 'part1', 'bom1' from dual union all
  3     select 'part1', 'bom1' from dual union all
  4     select 'part1', 'bom2' from dual union all
  5     select 'part1', 'bom2' from dual union all
  6     select 'part1', 'bom3' from dual union all
  7     select 'part1', 'bom4' from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 'part2', 'bom12' from dual union all
 10     select 'part2', 'bom13' from dual union all
 11     select 'part2', 'bom14' from dual union all
 12     select 'part2', 'bom15' from dual union all
 13     select 'part2', 'bom16' from dual union all
 14     select 'part2', 'bom17' from dual union all
 15     --
 16     select 'part3', 'bom14' from dual union all
 17     --
 18     select 'part4', 'bom14' from dual
 19    )
```

Query:

```
 20  select part, bom,
 21    dense_rank() over (partition by part order by bom) seq
 22  from temp;

PART  BOM          SEQ
----- ----- ----------
part1 bom1           1
part1 bom1           1
part1 bom2           2
part1 bom2           2
part1 bom3           3
part1 bom4           4
part2 bom12          1
part2 bom13          2
part2 bom14          3
part2 bom15          4
part2 bom16          5
part2 bom17          6
part3 bom14          1
part4 bom14          1

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```